# What do I need to do to get the ability to portal back to town?

Tags: diablo-iii

I thought this was extremely obvious, but I was so wrong. I looked for the town portal icon on the toolbar at the bottom, but it's not there? I checked again, no definitely not there! I checked key bindings. The <kbd>T</kbd> is supposed to portal me. Pressed it and nothing happened. This led me to think that this might be something I get later on in the game as there is no such thing as a Town Portal tome.

So what do I need to do to get the ability to portal back to town?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get Town Portal early in Act I, after retrieving Leoric's Crown (a quest on the main quest line).

Answer (score 1):

For people on console this is less obvious.
Press down on the D-pad, scroll over to Act and select your destination.
Took me awhile to find it because I guess I didn’t read the dialogue when I got the ability.